# freeswitch crash for libspeexdsp.so.1.5.0 error

Tags: freeswitch, speex

Hi！I had run a freeswitch for a callcenter ivr service.

During this time, freeswitch crash twice for the similar reasons below:

> freeswitch[39310]: segfault at 7f556d514638 ip 00007f55dd909dc6 sp
>   00007f556d514640 error 6 in **libspeexdsp.so.1.5.0**[7f55dd8ff000+12000]

---

> Dec  6 17:37:08 calltest kernel: freeswitch[19590]: segfault at
>   7f96ca9c8b18 ip 00007f96cb3b4dc6 sp 00007f96ca9c8b20 error 6 in
>   **libspeexdsp.so.1.5.0**[7f96cb3aa000+12000]

OS version: **CentOS release 6.6 (Final)**

freeswitch version: **FreeSWITCH Version 1.4.19~64bit (64bit)**

---

How can I find out what happen to freeswitch, and fixed the problem?

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0):

you need to upgrade FreeSWITCH to the latest version, and open a Jira ticket if the problem persists. You will need to attach as much as possible logs and information to the ticket, so that it's possible to analyze and maybe reproduce.

Also the best would be to migrate to FreeSWITCH version 1.6, as most of development is happening there, and the bugs get fixed faster.